# How to transform the conventional cell to primitive cell, by hand?

Tags: crystallography, symmetry

I am following [this tutorial](https://dannyvanpoucke.be/vasp-tutor-creating-a-unit-cell-from-a-super-cell-en/) to transform a conventional cell to a primitive cell, but I am not sure how to determine the primitive copy of some atom in the conventional cell.

For example, in the diamond structure of carbon, there are many carbon atoms in the conventional cell.

[image]

My question is:
**How should I determine (by hand!) the primitive copy of some atom in the conventional cell?**

Comment: Fastest way: use vaspkit

Comment: Pymatgen can also do this

Comment: I know how to use tools to do this, just wanna know how to do it by hand.

Comment: You can follow the instructions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Seitz_cell).

Comment: @Camps are you able to turn that comment into an answer eventually? It would be nice to have this question graduate from the unanswered queue!

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but now that it has been more than 1 year, can you update us please? Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer to this question? Did you figure it out? Maybe @Pranavkumar or AGS can write an answer?